# How to stop the baking in 2.8?

Tags: baking

I pressed the bake button, but forgot to change the range of the frames.
In blender 2.79 I could press the x button near the baking process.
How can I stop the baking in 2.8?
thanks

Answer (score 15):

ESC: Just press the Escape key.

Comment: Still works in 3.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is just the same, but now the loading bar is at the bottom.
[image]